# multiprocessing callback inside a method does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

I am trying to run multiprocessing inside a method. However callback does not seem to run properly.

Here is an example what I need to achieve.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep
import random

def sum(task, a, b): 
    sleepTime = random.randint(1, 4)
    print(task, " requires ", sleepTime, " seconds to finish")
    sleep(sleepTime)
    return a+b 

def printResult(result):
    print(result)

myPool = Pool(5)

result1 = myPool.apply_async(sum, args=("task1", 10, 20,), callback = printResult)
result2 = myPool.apply_async(sum, args=("task2", 20, 30,), callback = printResult)
result3 = myPool.apply_async(sum, args=("task3", 30, 40,), callback = printResult)
result4 = myPool.apply_async(sum, args=("task4", 40, 50,), callback = printResult)
result5 = myPool.apply_async(sum, args=("task5", 50, 60,), callback = printResult)

print("Submitted tasks to pool")

myPool.close()
myPool.join()
```

This works fine returning

```
Submitted tasks to pool
task1  requires  3  seconds to finish
task2  requires  4  seconds to finish
task3  requires  1  seconds to finish
task4  requires  4  seconds to finish
task5  requires  1  seconds to finish
110
70
30
50
90
```

However when I wrap multiprocessing inside a method and call that method, it does not seem to run as expected.

for example

```
def run_mp():
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    from time import sleep
    import random

    def sum(task, a, b): 
        sleepTime = random.randint(1, 4)
        print(task, " requires ", sleepTime, " seconds to finish")
        sleep(sleepTime)
        return a+b 

    def printResult(result):
        print(result)

    myPool = Pool(5)

    result1 = myPool.apply_async(sum, args=("task1", 10, 20,), callback = printResult)
    result2 = myPool.apply_async(sum, args=("task2", 20, 30,), callback = printResult)
    result3 = myPool.apply_async(sum, args=("task3", 30, 40,), callback = printResult)
    result4 = myPool.apply_async(sum, args=("task4", 40, 50,), callback = printResult)
    result5 = myPool.apply_async(sum, args=("task5", 50, 60,), callback = printResult)

    print("Submitted tasks to pool")

    myPool.close()
    myPool.join()
```

when `run_mp()` is called, it just returns the following.

```
Submitted tasks to pool
```

This is not just an issue with stdout printing on screen. In the actual problem I am dealing with does not seem to have correct call to callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer.  It's not possible, or at least easy, to pickle a class method with `multiprocessing`.  There's a fork of `multiprocessing`, called `multiprocess` (of which I'm the author), that uses the `dill` serializer... and enables exactly the kind of behavior you are looking for.

Simply replace the `from multiprocessing` with `from multiprocess` and your code runs as expected.